# Adding StackPanel To Grid.Children collection From another thread

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

I have a Panel which I build in the code and populate it with user controls.
When its done populating, I raise an event to the main GUI telling it the population is done and I pass the stack panel.

Then I want to add this panel to the container grid.

I have tried

```
   grdPbContent.Dispatcher.Invoke(
       DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
       new Action<StackPanel>(
           delegate(StackPanel _sp)
           {
                grdPbContent.Children.Add(_sp);
           }
       ),
       sp);`
```

and also the empty delegate option but always getting exception from the `TargetOfInvocation`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Create the stack panel on the thread that owns the grid

Comment: thanks Andy. But i'm creating the stack panel as a response to call back and in a sort of gui helper class so i'm looking for a diferent solution  - if one exsits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but it should work by simply using the dispatcher. Try using the dispatcher of the Window that contains the panel:

```
MyWindow.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate 
    {
        MyWindow.grdPbContent.Children.Add(_sp);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF objects cannot be modified by a thread other than the one that created them, so you can't create a `StackPanel` on one thread and add it to a `Grid` that was created on another thread

To do processing in the background, use the `Dispatcher` to run code at a different [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx), such as `Background`

You can use `Application.Current.Dispatcher` to get the UI thread for your current application from anywhere in your code.

If it's a really long process that will lock of the UI regardless of the priority it is run at, then get the data only from another thread, and build your UI objects on the main UI thread once the data has been returned.

Comment: hi Rachel thanks for the answer. this is exactly the problem.I have many long processing tasks which at the end of each one i'm raising an event to the main GUI telling him - update!. So i'm wondering  - will it be better to pass to the GUI just a list of user controls and then add them to the stack panel's child collection ? thanks in advance (have you modify my Ignorance ?..)